# Asp.net (find record between 2 dates) showing errors only to remote server & working fine in localhost

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to find record between 2 Dates. Which works fine in my localhost but after uploading to remote server it shows exception errors below.

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value) at myadmin_shipments.applyFilter()

I am taking date value in textbox & converting it to DateTime first & then putting it to MySQL query still it shows this error. But works fine in localhost. Is it because of my remote server has different time format?

```
DateTime dateTimefrom = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom.Text);
string myFromDate = string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", dateTimefrom);

DateTime dateTimeTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo.Text);
string myToDate = string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", dateTimeTo);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerCondition)) {
    customerCondition += " AND " + "DateOfBooking Between '" + myFromDate + "' AND '" + myToDate + "'";
} else {
    customerCondition += customerCondition + " AND " + " DateOfBooking Between '" + myFromDate + "' AND '" + myToDate + "'";
}
```

Comment: Can U take the complete request (write it in a file)  and see the difference between local and server ? It seems like your server and local don't work on same date format. Have u Same sql database on the machines?

Comment: @YannickIngenierie Yes that returns me some rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Regional Settings in both computers. Probably the server is different.

Then here

```
DateTime dateTimeTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo.Text);
```

you having the issue to convert.

so to fix this use this in your web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
</system.web>
```

in my case it's PT-BR, you use your current culture.

Comment: But does it matters when we convert format of date as per our requirement?

Comment: What text you have on it ? dateTo.Text ?

Comment: If the regional settings its like MM/dd/yyyy and you enter a date (text) like 13/05/2017 it will fail, because you are trying to convert a invalid date. So before check the regional settings, this is the reason that works in your machine, then you have to analyze if it's better change regional settings or fix your code to receive a correct date

Comment: dateFrom.Text is TextBox. myDateFrom is string. I am taking date from textbox in string & converting it to DateTime with server readable format.

Comment: My Localhost has date format dd/MM/yyyy. Here it's working. How do I check what is the format of Remote Server?

Comment: Yes, probably the issue is there, try to enter in your textbox like (from) 01/01/2017 and (to) 01/02/2017 and see if you have issues. Probably not?

Comment: You have remote desktop to the server? Or you only have access to host your asp.net page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150735/discussion-between-thiago-loureiro-and-sun).